# Why do I get the warning hint "Simplify boolean expression" in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I use Kotlin in Android Studio 3.01, I get the following warning hint for the code `if (isRegistered(mContext)==false )` in Code A.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

**Warning Hint**

*Simplify boolean expression. This inspections reports boolean expressions that have parts which can be reduced to constants*

**Code A**

```
public override fun onDestroy() {
        if (isRegistered(mContext)==false ) {
            if (isDebug()) {              
                openActivity(applicationContext, UIBuy::class.java)
            } else {
                openActivity(applicationContext, UIBuy::class.java)
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply change it to

```
if(!isRegistered(mContext))
```

The IDE will even suggest to make this change for you.

Comment: Thank you very much